# $Q\cap [a, b]$ is infinite

Tags: calculus

I need to show that $Q\cap [a, b]$ where $a, b\in R$ is an  infinite set.
I think it would be useful to recall that $Q$ is dense in $R$. But how it is done here?

Comment: Of course you must assume $a<b$.

Comment: @GEdgar The notation $[a,b]$ implies that.

Comment: @ajotatxe No, it doesn't.  Even if you rule out the empty case $(a > b)$, there is the case $a=b$ where $[a,a] = \{a\}$.

Comment: Yes, but how to explain this formally?

Comment: @ajotatxe: *The notation* $[a,b]$ *implies that* --- If you browse the literature some (online, or just flip though several calculus and real analysis texts), then you'll find that the notation $[a,b]$ sometimes disallows $a > b$ and sometimes disallows $a \geq b$ and sometimes has no restriction on the real numbers $a$ and $b$ (or more generally, on the elements in any given totally/linearly ordered set).

Answer (score 3):

We may assume that $a<b$.
Suppose that $\mathbb Q\cap[a,b]$ is finite. Then, there exist different numbers $(q_i)_{i=1}^n\subseteq\mathbb Q$ such that
$$\mathbb Q\cap[a,b]=\{q_1,\ldots,q_n\}$$
If $n=1$, we take a natural number $m$ such that $q_1+\frac{1}{m}<b$ or $a<q_1-\frac{1}{m}$, from where it follows that $q_1+\frac{1}{m}\in\mathbb Q\cap[a,b]$ or $q_1-\frac{1}{m}\in\mathbb Q\cap[a,b]$, which is a contradiction.
In other case, reindexing the $q_i$ we may assume that $q_1<\ldots<q_n.$
To conclude, notice that $\frac{q_1+q_2}{2}$ is a rational number lying in $[a,b]$, since $q_1,q_2\in[a.b]$, leading to a contradiction, since it is different from any $q_i$.

Comment: Your answer is similar to mine, posted just before me. However, we have written it slightly differently, and I will leave my answer up, as the different way of presenting our similar answers could be useful to someone relatively new to the idea of density.

Comment: The empty set is finite.

Comment: Heck, a set with just one element is finite as well, and would affect the validity of this answer too.

Comment: I think the OP may have doubts just in case $\emptyset\not=[a,b]\not\subseteq\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume, as suggested in the comments, that $a<b$.

Density of $Q$ gives you one element $p \in Q \cap (a,b) \subset [a,b]$. Now you have $a<p<b \in [a,b]$.

Density of $Q$ gives you one more element $q \in Q \cap (p,b) \subset [a,b]$. Now you have $a < p < q < b \in [a,b]$.

Closure of $Q$ under the operations of arithmetic gives you infinitely many elements of $Q \cap [a,b]$, for example
$$\frac{1}{n} \, p + \frac{n-1}{n} \, q \in [p,q] \subset [a,b]
$$

Comment: It's not a big difference, but I think $p+\frac{q-p}{n}$ is a little bit easier to see to be lying in $[p,q]$. My mathematical eyes can see that they're both just convex combinations of p and q, but I think this second version would be more obvious to beginners.

Comment: Perhaps. But I do love the convex combination formula $$[p,q] = \{t p + (1-t) q \mid t \in [0,1]\}$$

Comment: I'm with you on that.

Comment: Once you get two rationals, you can just take successive midpoints of intervals with rational endpoints; or just repeat the density argument in a dyadic fashion. And I'm sure you know this. (This note is mainly for others.) However, carefully writing either of these other ways in a way that is at what is likely the formal level the OP requires (i.e. probably are not allowed to say "and continue in the same way") might be more difficult.

Comment: Weird. This is the most straightforward and cleanest answer, and yet it's getting down votes and fewer up votes. I thought it might be because people thought the original question didn't meet the quality standards, so they were just down voting any answer, but apparently not? Sometimes I just don't get this place.<shrug>

Comment: @JonathanZ I agree with you.

Comment: @Deif - Yeah, yours is a nice answer too, and presents a different and useful approach, but has to handle those special cases. Definitely worth having here.

Comment: Yeah, I took a chance and a couple of quick downvotes. But it doesn't really matter, now there's lots of ideas/points of view.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a<b.$ It is easy to show there are at least two rational numbers in $[a,b].$ If there were finitely many, say $k\geq 2,$ rational numbers in $[a,b],$ then we can label these rationals in increasing order: $a \leq x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_k \leq b.$ This implies there is no rational number in the open interval $(x_1, x_2),$ which contradicts the density of rational numbers, because the density of a set $S$ (in this case the rational numbers) means (by definition) that every non-trivial/degenerate interval contains at least one member of $S.$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$n_0=\lceil\log_2 (b-a)\rceil$

Then, for $n\ge n_0$ there is at least an integer, odd number $k$ such that $a\leq\dfrac {k}{2^{n+1}}\leq b$. Namely, we can choose $k=\lceil 2^{n+1}a\rceil$ or  $k=\lceil 2^{n+1}a\rceil+1$.

So the set $A_n=\left\{\dfrac{k}{2^{n+1}}:a\leq \dfrac{k}{2^{n+1}}\leq b\wedge k\text{ is odd}\right\}$ is not empty for $n\ge n_0$.

So the set
$$\bigcup_{n=n_0}^\infty A_n\subset \Bbb Q\cap[a,b]$$
is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $m$ so that $m(b-a)\ge 3.$ Then $[ma,mb]$ contains an interval $[k,k+1].$ Hence $k+2^{-n}$ belong to $[k,k+1]\subset [ma,mb]$ for any natural number $n.$ Thus $m^{-1}(k+2^{-n})\in [a,b]$ for any $n.$